Date hierarchy including month and isoweek number, causing aggregate issues in visuals
I have created a date hierarchy year > month > isoweek > date.
I get a problem correctly visualizing aggregates using this hierarchy. Example: when presenting revenue in a matrix using this hierarchy, I get weeknumbers that are split over different months, so I never see the correct sum on the week-level.

When I want to retain drilldown function, for example with a column chart, I get two columns for week 9 (see second screenshot).

I understand the issue for PowerBI it needs to either aggregate on month or week level and can't do both. What sort of solution should I be looking for here? Ideally when drilling down, the 'month context' in the visual can become ambiguous as I'm looking at week-numbers; the dotted line could be on the week 9 column rather than splitting week 9.

I think you know the reason, The solution is either display week or month. If you display them together. The week will be split.

What sort of design choices can be considered otherwise?
